# How to address ProgramFile folder env variable while applying security on files using secedit

Tags: windows, security, permissions, file-permissions

I have a 32-bit application which also runs on 64-bit machine.I want to apply permissions to my delivered file using security template inf file and `secedit.exe`.

Currently, I maintain two inf files one with `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` and `%ProgramFiles%`.
And I take the decision to apply the inf based on OS.

```
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT secedit /configure /db c:\WINDOWS\security\Database\template.sdb /cfg c:\WINDOWS\security\templates\template.inf /log c:\WINDOWS\security\logs\template.log /verbose

if %OS%==64BIT secedit /configure /db c:\WINDOWS\security\Database\template_x86.sdb /cfg c:\WINDOWS\security\templates\template_x86.inf /log c:\WINDOWS\security\logs\template_x86.log /verbose
```

Is there is any way by which I can maintain only one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research over secedit.exe and found that if I invoke secedit.exe from `C:\Windows\Syswow64\secedit.exe` in case of 64 bit machine secedit.exe will treat `%ProgramFiles%` as `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)`.
So now i can have only one file and in if condition i'll use different secedit.exe to apply permissions